# App will run on device but not on iOS simulator

Tags: xcode4, ios-simulator, ios6, xcode4.5

I can run my app on my iPod Touch just fine but I can't run it on the Simulator. If I compile it for the simulator it builds fine but when it's about to run on the simulator, I get this error in the console

```
    dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SenTestingKit.framework/Versions/A/SenTestingKit
  Referenced from: /Users/bbrandy95/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/5BEEC98E-0F91-46C2-AF63-F695995A224D/Brandsonic Web mobile.app/Brandsonic Web mobile
  Reason: image not found
```

What's the issue here? It compiles fine but It won't run on the simulator. This is an older project created in Xcode 3 so it doesn't have the testing target. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that the library is actually in the path you specified (`@rpath/SenTestingKit.framework/Versions/A/SenTestingKit`)